# Utilizar data-values en funcion .slice - JQuery

Tags: jquery, html5, selectores-css

Desarrollo un calendario, y quiero simular la funcion de un "calendar range", es decir, seleccionar una fecha incio y una fecha fin, como esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el calendario, está en una tabla html

```
<div id="dncalendar-body" class="dncalendar-body">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>D</td>
                <td>L</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>J</td>
                <td>V</td>
                <td>S</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="" data-date="30" data-month="9" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">30</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="1" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">1</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="2" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">2</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="3" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">3</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="4" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">4</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="5" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">5</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="6" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">6</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="" data-date="7" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">7</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="8" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">8</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="9" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">9</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="10" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">10</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="11" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">11</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="12" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">12</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="13" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">13</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="" data-date="14" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">14</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="15" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">15</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" today-date  calendarClick" data-date="16" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry" data-title="hoy">16</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="17" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">17</div>
                </td>
                <td id="" class="" data-date="18" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">18</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="19" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">19</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="20" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">20</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="21" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">21</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="22" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">22</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="23" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">23</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="24" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">24</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="25" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">25</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="26" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">26</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="27" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">27</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="28" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">28</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="29" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">29</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="30" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">30</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="31" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">31</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" " data-date="1" data-month="11" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">1</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" " data-date="2" data-month="11" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">2</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" " data-date="3" data-month="11" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">3</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/MDcalendar.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

utilizo la funcion .slice de jquery.

```
$('table tbody td').slice(1,5).addClass("range");
```

y lo hago con los index de las celdas de la tabla, pero, por ejemplo el index del dia 22 es el mismo para el siguiente mes, con un día diferente

Es posible utilizar los "data" de las celdas como index en la funcion slide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice este snippet usando la función slice, pero capturando el índice global de la fecha de inicio y la fecha final. Dale un vistazo:

```js
let initIndex = null;
let finalIndex = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
  // Capturar evento click de las celdas del tbody
  $('table tbody td').click(function(){
    // Obtener el índice de la celda,
    // respecto a las demás celdas de la tabla
    let tdIndex = $('table tbody td').index(this);
    
    // Validar si se está escogiendo un nuevo rango de fecha
    // o si ya se escogió fecha final
    if(initIndex == null || finalIndex != null) {
      // Limpiar los estilos de todas las celdas de selección
      $('.primeraFecha').removeClass('primeraFecha');
      $('.ultimaFecha').removeClass('ultimaFecha');
      $('.fechaSeleccionada').removeClass('fechaSeleccionada');
      
      // Asignar el índice de la celda y limpiar el índice
      // de la fecha fin
      initIndex = tdIndex;
      finalIndex = null;
      
      // Agregar el estilo a la primera celda
      $(this).addClass('primeraFecha');
    } else {
      // Si el índice seleccionado es menor al ínidce de inicio
      // significa que la fecha de inicio es menor
      if(tdIndex < initIndex){
        // Limpiar el estilo de la fecha inicial anterior
        $('.primeraFecha').removeClass('primeraFecha');
        
        // Asignar el índice de la celda y limpiar el índice
        // de la fecha fin
        initIndex = tdIndex;
        finalIndex = null;
        
        // Agregar el estilo a la primera celda
        $(this).addClass('primeraFecha');
        
      // Si el índice seleccionado es igual al ínidce de inicio
      // significa que la fecha de inicio es la misma
      } else if(initIndex == tdIndex) {
      
        // Limpiar la fecha de inicio seleccionada
        initIndex = null;
        $(this).removeClass('primeraFecha');
        
      // Si el índice seleccionado es menor al ínidce de inicio
      // significa que se seleccionó fecha de fin
      } else {
      
        // Agregar estilo de fecha de fin
        $(this).addClass('ultimaFecha');
        finalIndex = tdIndex;
          
        // Si se encuentra dentro del rango de fechas, asignar
        // estilo de celda de fecha de rango
        $('table tbody td').slice(initIndex, finalIndex).addClass('fechaSeleccionada');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table thead td {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

table td div{
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

table tbody td {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

table tbody td:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: rgba(250, 165, 29, 0.5);
}

.primeraFecha div{
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}

.ultimaFecha div{
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}

.primeraFecha div, .ultimaFecha div, .fechaSeleccionada div{
  background-color: #faa51d;
  color: #fff;
}

.primeraFecha:hover, .ultimaFecha:hover, .fechaSeleccionada:hover{
  text-decoration: underline solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dncalendar-body" class="dncalendar-body">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>D</td>
                <td>L</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>J</td>
                <td>V</td>
                <td>S</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="" data-date="30" data-month="9" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">30</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="1" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">1</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="2" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">2</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="3" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">3</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="4" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">4</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="5" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">5</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="6" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">6</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="" data-date="7" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">7</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="8" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">8</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="9" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">9</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="10" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">10</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="11" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">11</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="12" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">12</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="13" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">13</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="" data-date="14" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">14</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="15" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">15</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" today-date  calendarClick" data-date="16" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry" data-title="hoy">16</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="17" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">17</div>
                </td>
                <td id="" class="" data-date="18" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">18</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="19" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">19</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="20" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">20</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="21" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">21</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="22" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">22</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="23" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">23</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="24" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">24</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="25" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">25</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="26" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">26</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="27" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">27</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="28" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">28</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="29" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">29</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="30" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">30</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="31" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">31</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" " data-date="1" data-month="11" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">1</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" " data-date="2" data-month="11" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">2</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" " data-date="3" data-month="11" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">3</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```